# Reducing Computation Time with Multiple Parameters

Tags: excel, powershell, if-statement, big-o

My script is running in O(n) time while checking multiple parameters; I'm seeking a way to get closer to O(1) time if possible.  Please ignore the fact that I am utilizing excel; there are other portions of the script that are utilizing the methods.  All suggestions are appreciated.

```
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count  
$count = 0
$countDelete = 0

#Declare the starting positions
$rowCompName,$colCompName = 1,3

#Checking Loop
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++){                   
    $CompName = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowCompName+$i,$colCompName).text.ToUpper()

    #Items Processed
    $count++

    #Removal of non-ND machines
    if($CompName -eq ''){
        continue
    }

    $CompName = $CompName.Substring(0,5)    

    if($CompName -ne "Name1" -and $CompName -ne "Name2" -and $CompName -ne "Name3" -and $CompName -ne "Name4") {
        $returnsTrue = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowCompName+$i,$colCompName).EntireRow.Delete()
        $rowsDeleted++ 
        $i--   
        $rowMax--
        $countDelete++
    }

}
```

Comment: You might get a better response from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since you have working code you are needing optimized.

Comment: By multiple parameters, do you mean the `$CompName -ne "Name1" -and $CompName -ne "Name2" -and $CompName -ne "Name3" -and $CompName -ne "Name4"` part? Or is there something else?

Comment: Are you allowed to sort your spreadsheet?  Sorting as implemented in a program is typically O(n log n) at worst.  Then you only need to search for the first cell that begins with the searched value, and then check subsequent cells until you find a value that isn't correct.  You could use [`WorksheetFunction.Search`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-search-method-excel) to find the first value, too, which is probably faster than having PowerShell do it.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding.  @K.Davis --I wasn't aware of that; thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yes, that portion that is checking weather the value matches or can be deleted.

Comment: @BaconBits Do you know the base module so I can look at the man file related to it and see all of the functions?  I am not sure if you are pulling those function from the excel module or some native powershell module.

Comment: @LifeOfThePotty It's the same as the Excel VBA model.  It's the one I linked above with the WorksheetFunction.Search, or here for the top of the object model: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/object-model-excel-vba-reference

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few things that are slowing you down here. At the very least making multiple calls to the comobject is slowing you down. You could make a RegEx match or use the `-in` operator and just check if the name is in a list of names. There's also the option of using the `Switch` command and making cases, but I'm not sure how much that would speed things up for you. Just a quick look would tell me to try this:

```
$InitialRows = $Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
$Excludes = 'NAME1','NAME2','NAME3','NAME4',$null
$Sheet.UsedRange.Rows | Where{$_.Cells.Item(3).Value2.ToUpper().Substring(0,5) -notin $Excludes} | ForEach{$_.EntireRow.Delete() | Out-Null}
$RowsDeleted = $InitialRows - $Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

That'll keep any row that has nothing in the third cell, or matches the 4 names you specified.

If you are working with a newer version of PowerShell that has the `Get-Clipboard` cmdlet you can grab the strings, and make an array of objects fairly quickly to work with the data in PowerShell, then clear the sheet and paste the results back in. I'll use a RegEx match here instead of the `-in` operator.

```
$Excludes = 'NAME1','NAME2','NAME3','NAME4'
$RegEx = ($Excludes | %{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join '|'
$sheet.UsedRange.Copy() | Out-Null
$dataImport = Get-Clipboard | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t"
$Sheet.UsedRange.Clear() | Out-Null
$dataImport.Where({[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.ServerName) -or $_.ServerName.Substring(0,5) -match "^$RegEx"}) | ConvertTo-Csv -Del "`t" -NoType | Clip
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1).PasteSpecial() | Out-Null
```

That should do the same thing as the first, though I didn't do anything to count rows, but with all the data still in PowerShell you could count rows or do whatever processing you want with it. As for the `Switch` command, I don't think it's a great option, but if you want an example I could write one up easily enough.

Comment: I will give your suggestions a shot.  Thank you for the input